# Using a URL instead of a form to add a shapefile to a layer in JavaScript

Tags: shapefile, javascript, html, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have the following code that is used to add a shapefile to the map and it works perfectly.

```
var genRequest = request({
                    url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
                    content: myContent,
                    form: dom.byId('uploadForm2'),
                    handleAs: 'json',
                    load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                        if (response.error) {
                            return;
                        }
                        addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
                    }),
                });
```

However currently it is using a form where the user has to manually select a file from on his pc.
Is there any way so that instead of using the form I can pass a link which is passed through the code? I can't seem to code the form dynamically to automatically accept the link to avoid the user having the choose the file either.